# Inconsistency Regarding Commutators and Integration?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, field-theory, integration, commutator

I have this following confusion regarding the ordering of integration and commutator.

Consider an operator $\mathcal{O}$ defined as
$$
\mathcal{O}(t) \equiv \int d^3 x' \ \phi(t, \vec{x}') \nabla'^2 \phi(t, \vec{x}')
$$
where $\nabla^2$ is the spatial Laplacian, and $\phi(x)$ is the massless Klein-Gordon field given by
$$
\phi(x) = \int \frac{d^3 p}{\sqrt{(2 \pi)^3 2 \omega_p}} \left( a_p e^{-i p \cdot x} + a_p^{\dagger} e^{i p \cdot x} \right) 
$$

There seems to be two ways of evaluating the commutator $[\phi(t, \vec{x}), \mathcal{O}(t)]$:

1. **Evaluate the commutator first**, i.e.
   $$
   [\phi(t, \vec{x}), \mathcal{O}(t)] = \int d^3 x' \ [\phi(t, \vec{x}), \phi(t, \vec{x}') \nabla'^2 \phi(t, \vec{x}')] 
   $$
   Using the fact that $[A, B C] = [A, B] C + B [A, C]$, we are left with
   $$
   [\phi(t, \vec{x}), \mathcal{O}(t)] = \int d^3 x' \ \phi(t, \vec{x}') \nabla'^2 [\phi(t, \vec{x}), \phi(t, \vec{x}')] = 0 
   $$
   due to the equal-time commutation relation for $\phi$.
2. **Carry out the integral $\int d^3 x'$ first**, i.e.
   $$
   [\phi(t, \vec{x}), \mathcal{O}(t)] = \left[ \phi(t, \vec{x}), \int d^3 x' \ \phi(t, \vec{x}') \nabla'^2 \phi(t, \vec{x}') \right] 
   $$
   The integral gives
   \begin{align}
   \mathcal{O}(t) &= \int d^3 x' \ \phi(t, \vec{x}') \nabla'^2 \phi(t, \vec{x}') \\
   &= -\int \frac{d^3 p}{2 \omega_p} \ \vec{p}^2 \left( e^{-2 i \omega_p \ t} a_p \ a_{-p} + a_p a_p^{\dagger} + \mathrm{h.c.} \right) 
   \end{align}
   which does NOT commute with $\phi(t, \vec{x})$!

This "inconsistency" has bothered me for a while, and I can't figure out where I've made a mistake.

Am I missing something here? Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: haven’t thought about things that carefully yet, but you seem to multiply two operators at the same point in order to define ${\cal O}(t)$. This is not so obvious a step and requires normal ordering. ${\cal O}(t)$ cannot be treated as a simple product of operators. (It’s 3AM here, I’ll think about this more carefully in the morning).

Comment: @Prahar Thank you very much for taking the time. I think we can view the operator $\mathcal{O}$ as the interaction Hamiltonian related to a local quadratic interaction.

Comment: The problem is probably the first case where you seem to assume that the Laplacian of the result of the commutation will give you zero. Using partial integration you should be able to transfer the Laplacian to the remaining field and then evaluate the integration with the result of the commutation to obtain something that is not zero.

Comment: @flippiefanus Hi, thank you for the comment. I don't quite get your idea. I think the integrand in the first case has to be zero, which can also be seen from 
$$
[\phi(t, \vec{x}), \partial_t \ \pi(t, \vec{x}')] = \partial_t \ [\phi(t, \vec{x}), \pi(t, \vec{x}')] - [\pi (t, \vec{x}), \pi(t, \vec{x}')] = i \partial_t \ \delta^3 (\vec{x} - \vec{x}') = 0
$$
Note: I have substituted the Laplacian with $\partial_t^2$ using the field equation.